# i can't hide an object in visual basic using vs for windows 8?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-store

**hello everyone !**

I am making an app in vb to distribute it in windows store, but I'm having a problem.

I've put a button and picture box which named ((image1)) so when click the button the picture box will hide.

what I know the code must be like that:

```
 Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        image1.visible = false
End Sub
```

i tried this in vs for windows desktop and it's works.
but when i try this in vs for windows 8 it tells me Error   1   'visible' is not a member of 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image'.

please help i have a project just this little bit and it will done.
thanks.

Comment: Looking at [the docs for Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image.aspx) there doesn't appear to be a `Visible` property.  Perhaps you meant `Visibility`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A day and no answers, but i found the solution...

All you must do is replace visible=false with visibility = windows.UI.Xaml.visibility.collapsed or with windows.UI.Xaml.visibility.visible and it's all done...

Comment: Well, the answer is under your question as comment. It didn't even deserve to use answer function.